# how does 3d auto mode work with projectors

Tags: htpc, projector, home-theater

I have my Epson home cinema 3000 plugged into my computer with an HDMI cable

I can watch 3D movies that play in side by side mode by manually switching my projector to 3D. The movie of course needs to be displaying as side by side.

There is a setting called "3D Auto" on the projector. Presumably the projector can Auto discover 3D movies that are being played. How does this work? Does the Blu-ray player or device send the projector some kind of special signal? Can that be done from my PC?

Just really curious how that actually works